# Python read txt file as input: IndexError: list index out of range?

Tags: python, list, indexing

Here is my code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  fid = open ('200502.txt')
  data = fid.readlines()
  data = map (string.strip, data)
  x = []
  y = [] 
  da = []
  for d in data:
    s = d.split()
    x.append(float(s[0])/10000.0)
    y.append(float(s[1])/10000.0)
    da.append(float(s[2]))
```

When I run it I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot_data.py", line 286, in ?
    x.append(float(s[0])/10000.0)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The 200502.txt (840kb) file is like:

```
1131087 224529 3.923   
1131096 224529 3.958 
1131106 224530 3.897    
1131116 224530 3.917   
1131126 224530 3.847 
(....)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a fragile way to load your data.  My guess is it's breaking on a newline at the end of the file, or something like that.  Regardless, you should load your file with `numpy.loadtxt` instead (or `csv` module if you don't have access to `numpy`).

To get you started on that:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> data = numpy.loadtxt('/tmp/200502.txt')
>>> xs = data.T[0]/10000.
>>> ys = data.T[1]/10000.
>>> da = data.T[2]
```

Comment: If we are getting in to questions of style, loading the x, y, and data values from each line in to separate lists is somewhat of a questionable decision to begin with.  A list of objects, lists, tuples, or dicts would seem to be more sensible.

Comment: @sr2222: It is easy to fix: `x,y,da = np.loadtxt('200502.txt', unpack=True); x *= 1e-5; y *= 1e-5`

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one element in your input file that contains no data.  You are iterating over `data`, and one of the elements is producing a 0-length list from `d.split()`.  I'd also suggest considering loading your data in to a more structured organization.  Something like `loaded_data = [zip(('x', 'y', 'da'), d.split()) for d in data]`.